# how to send temperature readings from nodemcu to raspberrypi wirelessly

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, esp8266, nodemcu

how to send temperature readings from nodemcu to raspberrypi wirelessly and store it in a database. Can somebody provide me with a tutorial. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MQTT protocol to send data to raspberry pi from nodemcu. On raspberry pi python script will subscribe to mqtt topic where data is received and can be stored into database.